# fetching core data displaying number of items in array not strings

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, label

My code below fetches Core Data. The problem is that the Core Data fetch should display the names. Example "Ron", "Paul", "Joe". Instead it will just be 3 for the number of items in the array. How can I get the name printed on the label?

```
class tv: UIViewController {
    var itemsName : [NSManagedObject] = []

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let FetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Team")

        do {
            itemsName = try context.fetch(FetchRequest)
        }catch {
            print("Ashley Tisdale")
        }

        geroge.text = String(itemsName.count)

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    }

    @IBOutlet var geroge: UILabel!
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually printing the number of items in the array.

Also you should change the `FetchRequest` like this:

```
let FetchRequest = Team.fetchRequest()
```

Now the `itemsName` is `[Team]` type.

Now create an array to store the names from the results like this:

```
var nameArray:[String] = []
for item in itemsName {
    nameArray.append(item.name) // here I assume the Team object has the key name which you want to retrieve
}
```

Now you can have it printed:

```
george.text = "\(nameArray)"
```

**Edit**

Replace this:

```
let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
let FetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Team") 
do { 
    itemsName = try context.fetch(FetchRequest)
}catch { 
    print("Ashley Tisdale")
} 
geroge.text = String(itemsName.count)
```

With this:

```
let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
let FetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Team> = Team.fetchRequest() 

do { 
    itemsName = try context.fetch(FetchRequest)
}catch { 
    print("Ashley Tisdale")
} 

var nameArray:[String] = []
for item in itemsName {
    nameArray.append(item.lorde)
}
geroge.text = "\(nameArray)"
```

And change data type of `itemsName` from `[NSManagedObjects]` to `[Team]` like this:

```
var itemsName:[Team] = []
```

Comment: I am getting this error Cannot invoke initializer for type 'init(_:)' with an argument list of type '([NSManagedObject])'

Comment: Yes actually the array is of type NSManagedObjects. You can get the names from the objects and put in a different array and then use that array

Comment: I added a picture of coreData. I tried you added code but I did not know where to put it.

Comment: Just replace `item.name` with `item.lorde`.

Comment: So what do I put in View Did appear?

Comment: I am still getting errors check out the screenshot above.

Comment: Check it now. And dont forget to change the data type of `itemNames` as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Its better but I am still getting a new error. I updated the picture above. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I mentioned it in the answer and also told you to change the data type of `itemNames` from `[NSManagedObjects]` to `[Team]`

Comment: Thats it you the man. You have to wrap lorde! but thats it. It works.